# Is Blender's default (non-node, "nothing") material the default material in all 3d apps?

Tags: materials, color

Is Blender's default material (non-node, not rendered in Cycles, or "Viewport material" if you will) the default material in all 3D apps? I don't really know exactly how it works, but I notice that Photoshop and another non-2D app I use can import .obj models with the exact viewport colors and the exact same glossiness of this default material, so I'm supposing it must be a very common material because I don't see any affiliation between these programs and Blender.

Comment: It is just a generic flat grey render through OpenGL which doesn't really add much personality to make it distinct from other apps

Comment: Now I notice the .mtl files come with the .obj files. Apparently they store material information, including the viewport colors and speculars of an unwrapped model. Without them, other programs won't import the colors.